# prove the following: $a⋅(b\times c)=(a\times b)⋅c$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Prove the following:

$a⋅(b\times c)=(a\times b)⋅c$

all letters are vectors, the x is cross product, the ⋅ is dot product

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Mind sharing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hint $a \cdot (b \times c) = det(a,b,c)$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\vec{a}\cdot\pars{\vec{b}\times\vec{c}} & =
\sum_{i}a_{i}\pars{\vec{b}\times\vec{c}}_{i} =
\sum_{i}a_{i}\pars{\sum_{jk}\color{#f00}{\epsilon_{jki}}b_{j}c_{k}} =
\sum_{k}\pars{\sum_{ij}\color{#f00}{\epsilon_{ijk}}a_{i}b_{j}}c_{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k}\pars{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}_{k}c_{k} = \bbx{\ds{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}}}
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{jki}}$.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite formulation of this is that if $a,b,c$ are row vectors, then

$$a \cdot (b \times c) = \det \left( \begin{matrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{matrix} \right) $$

This is particularly easy to see by comparing to the mnemonic for the cross product

$$ b \times c = \det \left( \begin{matrix}
\mathbf{\vec{i}} & \mathbf{\vec{j}} & \mathbf{\vec{k}}  
\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{matrix} \right) $$

By permuting the rows around, we get the matrix computing $c \cdot (a \times b) = (a \times b) \cdot c$.

Comment: p.s. I prefer to make $a,b,c$ the columns of the matrix rather than the rows, but I wrote it this way in my answer since the formula above is how I've always seen the cross product mnemonic written.